# Use of Undeclared Identifier "angle"?

Tags: c++, reference, identifier, reference-parameters

I am making a program that converts rectangular coordinates into polar coordinates and whenever I go to run the program it tells me that the "angle" is undeclared even though I am sure I have declared it. As well I know that the program isn't returning anything, I just want to be able to run it for now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double random_float(double min, double max);
void rect_to_polar(double x, double y, double &distance, double &angle);

int main() {
    double x, y;
    x = random_float(-1, 1);
    y = random_float(-1, 1);

    rect_to_polar(x, y, distance, angle);
}

double random_float(double min, double max) {
    unsigned int n = 2;
    srand(n);
    return ((double(rand()) / double(RAND_MAX)) * (max - min)) + min;
}


void rect_to_polar(double x, double y, double &distance, double &angle) {
    const double toDegrees = 180.0/3.141593;

    distance = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
    angle = atan(y/x) * toDegrees;

}
```

Comment: Where did you declare it?

Comment: You never declared `distance` or `angle` in `main`.

Comment: "Answered" does not belong in the title. If an answer solved your problem, accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not declare anything called `angle` in your `main()`, but still used the name `angle` there. Thus the error.

You might want to read up on [scopes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope).

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `distance` and `angle` in your main.

```
int main() {
    double x, y, angle, distance;
    x = random_float(-1, 1);
    y = random_float(-1, 1);

    rect_to_polar(x, y, distance, angle);
}
```